# Structure to hold 3 columns and lookup for a row fast by any of the columns

Tags: c#, data-structures, hashtable

We had one hashtable as a readonly reference to a list of values like this:

```
internal static readonly Hashtable relationcodeAcodeB = new Hashtable
{
    {"149", "23"},
    {"139", "17"}
}
```

Now we need an structure that can hold 3 values(columns) and look up a value fast by any of the other 2.

Something like this:

```
internal static readonly Hashtable relationcodeAcodeBcodeC = new Hashtable
{
    {"149", "23", "xx"},
    {"139", "17", "xxx"}
}
string codeB=relationcodeAcodeBcodeC[codeA="149"]["codeB"];
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using generic collections?

Comment: This is actually a pretty interesting question (upvote!); obviously there are multiple solutions to this but I'm curious as to what the fastest/cleanest or even correct way to do this is.

BTW you should clarify: the title says by any of the columns, while the question reads by any of the other **two**. Quite the difference.

Comment: Agree with Cloud - this could be an interesting question if you'd clarify it.

Comment: Well i dont see the confusion...if you search for column A you would do it by the other two not the one you are looking for wouldnt you? How would you clarify the title then?

Comment: @Jon Skeet i was using hashtable because it was the fastest/easiest (in theory) way to have this data and access to it, now that we have 3 columns it doesnt apply...if you know some way to do it as simple with 3 columns and generic collections feel free to drop an answer ;)

Comment: I think I already understand, my bad. I thought you meant searching with an input of two values instead of one. But you always search with one input, and want to output two?

Comment: I want to search with one input and get one output...
Search for codeA being codeB="x"

Comment: @ase69s, you *do* realize I proposed a potential solution about 15 minutes ago, don't you? I'm starting to feel invisible.

Comment: @zmbq sorry i was thinking about your solution and how i would implement it while clarifing my question...i will reply to it now

Comment: It's Ok, I was just worried for some reason it disappeared and only I can see it...

Comment: Doesnt exist something like datatable but optimized for this cases?
i mean in datatable you can filter by one of the columns and get any of the columns in the returned row...

Comment: @ase69s well an in-memory database would do the trick, but I really don't think zmbq his/her solution is that difficult. Still wondering if there are more 'intelligent' (by lack of a better word) solutions to this.

Comment: @ase69s: In what way would Hashtable be easier than `Dictionary<,>`? Using the non-generic collections is extremely odd these days.

Comment: @cloud i used zmbq solution, i meant difficult in the sense that you need to implement more logic than the original code with hashtables. More than 'intelligent' would be 'suited/integrated/compact' solution for this case that popups frequently...

Comment: @JonSkeet in the original case i had a relation between two strings and hashtable seemed the best tool for the work, i what aspect would dictionary up hashtable for this case?

Comment: @ase69s: It would be type safe. You wouldn't need to cast when fetching a value, and you wouldn't be able to add a value with the wrong type of key etc. How familiar are you with the generic collections?

Comment: @JonSkeet Somewhat familiar, but didnt know hashtables made casts when fetching or adding, up to now i thought it was the fastest object for lookups etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say your object has three properties codeA, codeB and codeC, you maintain three hash tables, like so:

```
Dictionary<string, MyObj> dictA, dictB, dictC;
```

When creating a new `MyObj`, you add it to the three dictionaries:

```
dictA[obj.codeA] = obj;
dictB[obj.codeB] = obj;
dictC[obj.codeC] = obj;
```

Looking up is very easy. Your example will be coded as `dictA["149"].codeB`

Keep it all tidy in one big lookup class, of course.

Comment: Doesnt it seem too complex for simply having another column? this would mean having 3 different dictionaries and filling them separatelly...

Comment: It depends, do you want the lookup to be efficient? This way the lookup is done in O(1). And it's really not all that hard to implement. If you want to just scan your list of objects and find the right one, you're going to end up with an O(N) solution that's a little bit lengthier, too.

Comment: Im implementing it like this as a trial, but it gets a lot more lines of code to initialize than the hashtable and cant be readonly anymore...it seems strange that this case hasnt been handled by a better suited object up to now

Comment: No, no, create a looking-up class for performing the lookup, and hide the three dictionaries inside it. Your lookup instance can be readonly.